# Cannot read property 'enterText' of undefined using pageobject method in step definitions

Tags: javascript, bdd

I am using page object method in step function but am getting Cannot read property 'enterText' of undefined. Code in cucumber step function looks like:

```
When(/^I enter "([^"]*)" into the search box$/, function(arg1) {
  RedditPage.enterText.setValue(arg1);
  RedditPage.searchInput.getValue().should.equal(arg1);
  });
page object has:
async enterText (item) {
    this.searchInput.clearElement();
    this.searchInput.setValue(item);
  }
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The `RedditPage` is undefined here, likely it was not loaded before executing failing 2nd line of your code.

Comment: I have imported RedditPage via import { RedditPage } from ../ so should be loaded, sorry I think your comment is truncated for some reason..